# Bootstrap collapsing panels overlap each other when I use Masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, masonry

I have the next page:

```js
    $(function () {
        var container = document.querySelector('#PanelContainer');
        var msnry = new Masonry(container, {
            itemSelector: '.selector-class',
            isAnimated: true,
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
            }   
        });
        $(".spoiler-trigger").click(function () {
            $(this).parent().next().collapse('toggle');
        });
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div id="PanelContainer" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 selector-class">
        <div class="panel panel-primary card-0">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs spoiler-trigger" data-toggle="collapse">Collapse</button>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-collapse collapse out">
              <div class="panel-body">Body</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 selector-class">
        <div class="panel panel-primary card-0">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs spoiler-trigger" data-toggle="collapse">Collapse</button>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-collapse collapse out">
              <div class="panel-body">Body</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 selector-class">
        <div class="panel panel-primary card-0">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs spoiler-trigger" data-toggle="collapse">Collapse</button>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-collapse collapse out">
              <div class="panel-body">Body</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 selector-class">
        <div class="panel panel-primary card-0">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs spoiler-trigger" data-toggle="collapse">Collapse</button>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-collapse collapse out">
              <div class="panel-body">Body</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

All looks perfect but when the user tries to expand any panels that overlaps others. How can I make to Masonry recalculates and smooth updates panels' locatons?
P.S. I am a noobie in JS.

**ADDED**
I set listeners for Bootstrap events:

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    msnry.layout();
});
$(document).on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    msnry.layout();
});
```

And my layout began to update self but if it has a wrong behavior for expanding. Now, the panel expanded and after it calls layout updating but I need to make it before.

Comment: I guess you cannot make the change before bootstrap change sizes (before the animation). It first expands and changes height, and after that masonry knows what sizes should it use for layouting.

Comment: What you can do, is put each bootrap element into some container (so basically split col-md-6 from .selector-class. And in jquery before hand resize container, run collapse animation and at the same time run mnsry.layout()... but it needs to be checked.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try... Although, I don't sure that the masonry can stage all blocks correct in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this can help, i got this working, but only when using `col-XX-[3/6/12]` (due to the requirement on `width:` being a nice %age)

It's a tad messy, but functional.

### things worth changing/noting:

to get around the layout change on collapse/expand, the JS has a `setTimeout` that runs on the update; in production, or especially for slower animated expand/collapse sequences, i imagine a better solution would need to be found. but for animations less than 100ms, i reckon you'd get away with this.

On the CSS, if you used any bootstrap column bigger than `xs`, you'd need to adapt the css `grid-item[-6,-12]` to match the `col` rules for changing width % with screen size.

Mostly the bootstrap column rules take precedence, so things dont get too wrecked.

[NB: my .click event is bound to the text header on the panel, not the panel header div]

```js
$('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  percentPosition: true,

});

$('.panel-heading').click(function () {
 setTimeout(function() {
  $('.grid').masonry('layout');
 }, 300);
});
```

```css
.grid-sizer, .grid-item {width: 25%;}

.grid-item--width-6 { width: 50%;}

.grid-item--width-12 { width: 100%;}

/* NOT required to work,it 
helps demo whats going on */
.panel-body {
 height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">



<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>

  <div class=" col-xs-12 grid-item grid-item--width-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse0-m">panel 0</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse0-m" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class=" col-xs-6 grid-item grid-item--width-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1-m">panel 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1-m" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 grid-item grid-item--width-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">
       <h4 class="panel-title">
         <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2-m">panel 2</a>
       </h4>
     </div>
     <div id="collapse2-m" class="panel-collapse collapse">
       <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-3 grid-item">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse3-m">panel 3</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3-m" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-3 grid-item">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse4-m">panel 4</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse4-m" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 grid-item grid-item--width-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse5-m">panel 5</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse5-m" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>



    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Although we released this app already =)